# Vim command to increment number digit ONLY at cursor position in a longer number string?

Tags: vim

I have a few instances where I want to do the following

In file:

```
1234
```

With the cursor at the 1st digit, I want to use Ctrl-A to increment the digit so that I get

```
2234
```

instead of

```
1235
```

Are there intrinsic vim commands to do this?

Otherwise, should I set up a quick script:

1. Surround digit with leading and trailing space
2. Ctrl-A to increment
3. Delete leading and trailing space

Like so, and then map to a key?

Comment: This has been discussed already here (can't find the question). It can't get any simpler and quicker than `r#` (where `#` is the new number).

Comment: I will clarify that I want to extend this idea to a macro or script, so if I have, say 100 data points, I need something more general, I'll edit the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The increment function takes a leading number like most vim commands.  `1000 ctrl+a` would return `2234` like you wanted. If all your numbers are 4 digits numbers then this would work. Or you could use `r2` which replaces the current character under the cursor with a `2`, but this may be too specific.

If you need your script you can record a macro.

`qaa[space][esc]h[ctrl+a]lx`

broken down:

`qa` - start recording a `q` macro and save to register `a`

`a[space][esc]` - add a space after number

`h` - move back to number

`ctrl+a` - add one

`lx` move right and delete space.

You shouldn't need to add a leading space, because as you noticed the `ctrl+a` function acts on the number as a whole and will always add 1.

Answer (score 4):

You could do this as `s<C-r>=<C-r>"+1<Enter>`.

You can then map that to something else, like `nnoremap g<C-a> s<C-r>=<C-r>"+1<cr>` (you'll need to use <kbd>Ctrl-v</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-r</kbd> to insert the `<C-r>`s in this normal map).

### Step by step:

`s`  - delete the character under the cursor and begin insertion

`<C-r>=` - begin an expression evaluation.

`<C-r>"` - put contents of unnamed register in

> See :help i_CTRL-r for more information on these.

`+1<Enter>` - add 1 to the value and complete the command.

Comment: The `yl` step is superfluous, since `s` deletes character saving it in the default register.  So, `s` `Ctrl`+`R` `=@"+1` `Enter` `Esc` commands are enough.